# How to make dynamic pivot for this table when I pass only one parameter @did int?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have two tables, `@DETAILS` and `@CONTACTDETAILS`. In those two tables, `@DETAILS` is a static table in which `contactid` will be the primary key, and it will be the foreign key for the `@CONTACTDETAILS`

Here are the tables with data:

```
DECLARE  @DETAILS TABLE (CONTACTID  INT IDENTITY(1,1), VALUE VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @DETAILS
    SELECT  'PHONENUMBER' UNION ALL
    SELECT  'MOBILENUMBER' UNION ALL
    SELECT  'ADDRESS1' UNION ALL
    SELECT  'ADDRESS2'  UNION ALL
    SELECT  'EMPLOYEENAME'  UNION ALL
    SELECT  'EMPLOYEEID'

DECLARE  @CONTACTDETAILS TABLE (DETAILID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
                                DID INT,
                                CONTACTID INT, 
                                DETAILSVALUE VARCHAR(200)
                               )

INSERT INTO @CONTACTDETAILS
    SELECT  1,5,'SIVA' UNION ALL
    SELECT  1,6,'SIA001' UNION ALL
    SELECT  1,2,'9344139991' UNION ALL
    SELECT  2,1,'245678' UNION ALL
    SELECT  2,2,'1686597' UNION ALL
    SELECT  2,5,'GANESH' UNION ALL
    SELECT  1,3,'ST-ROAD'

SELECT * FROM @DETAILS
```

The output from this is:

```
CONTACTID VALUE
----------------------
1         PHONENUMBER
2         MOBILENUMBER
3         ADDRESS1
4         ADDRESS2
5         EMPLOYEENAME
6         EMPLOYEEID


SELECT * FROM @CONTACTDETAILS
```

The output for this second query is:

```
DETAILID DID CONTACTID DETAILSVALUE
-----------------------------------
1        1   6         SIVA
2        1   5         SIA001
3        1   2         9344139991
4        2   1         245678
5        2   2         1686597
6        2   5         GANESH
7        1   3         ST-ROAD
```

In the `@CONTACTDETAILS` column I have a value of the `DID` column which I used to show one particular employee detail in my stored procedure I am using

Parameter `@DID int` - I just tried this query

```
declare @DID int=1
  SELECT 
     (SELECT VALUE FROM @DETAILS WHERE CONTACTID=A.CONTACTID)AS CONTACTID,
     A.DETAILSVALUE
  FROM 
     @CONTACTDETAILS A
     WHERE
       A.DID=@DID
```

which will show the result like this

```
CONTACTID   DETAILSVALUE
EMPLOYEEID  SIVA
EMPLOYEENAME    SIA001
MOBILENUMBER    9344139991
ADDRESS1    ST-ROAD
```

and now  i am  trying output like this

```
EMPLOYEEID  EMPLOYEENAME  MOBILENUMBER   ADDRESS1
SIA001      SIVA          9344139991       ST-ROAD
```

can any  one plz help me

Comment: thanks paul  for editing  my question i dont know  how  to show table  in a gray but u didi that thanks a lot

Comment: To format code, tables, etc you highlight the text and use the `{}` button on the toolbar to apply formatting.

Answer (score 4):

The basic set up if you know the value ahead of time will be:

```
select *
from
(
  select c.did,
    d.value,
    c.detailsvalue
  from DETAILS d
  inner join CONTACTDETAILS c
    on d.CONTACTID = c.CONTACTID
) src
pivot
(
  max(detailsvalue)
  for value in (EMPLOYEEID, EMPLOYEENAME, ADDRESS1,
                MOBILENUMBER, PHONENUMBER)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc5f4f/5)

The above gets you all of the values but if you want to implement dynamic SQL to filter the result based on the `@did`, then you will use:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @did int

set @did = 1

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(d.value) 
                    from DETAILS d
                    inner join CONTACTDETAILS c
                      on d.CONTACTID = c.CONTACTID
                    where c.did = @did
                    group by d.value, c.DETAILID
                    order by c.DETAILID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
                select 
                  d.value,
                  c.detailsvalue
                from DETAILS d
                inner join CONTACTDETAILS c
                  on d.CONTACTID = c.CONTACTID
                where c.did = '+cast(@did as varchar(10))+'
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(detailsvalue)
                for value in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc5f4f/5)